# Store and code values of range sliders as embedded data field in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, slider, qualtrics

I would like to store the values of several range sliders, code them as "0"/"1", add them up and store the sum in an embedded data field in Qualtrics. However, with my code below, it only codes and stores the value of the last moved slider.
How can I circumvent that and store the values of all sliders?

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('more-left');
var len     = sliders.length;

for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    var slider = sliders[i];

    slider.addEventListener('change', function() {
        updateValue(this);
    });

    updateValue(slider);
}

function updateValue(slider) {
    var id        = slider.id;

    if (!id) {
        return;
    }

    var val       = document.getElementById(id + '_value');


    if (val) {
        val.innerHTML = slider.value; 
    }
var question_text = slider.value
if (question_text == 50) {
 score = 1;
}
else {
    score = 0;
} 

    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Output",score);}});
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you want to increment score (`score++;`) rather than reset it to 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The final aim is to assign 1 score point if a slider has been "correctly" dragged to 50 and no score point otherwise. This should work for all sliders, not just the one which has been dragged last. These "1´s" should be summed and stored as the total score. I am not sure how to achieve this with increment/decrement. Help would be much appreciated! Thank you.